# Nginx seems to be reverting to a directory of files?

Tags: nginx, centos

I'm trying to run [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) on my own VPS mostly for the learning experience (and here we are).

When I SSH in and start/restart nginx my [blog URL](http://austenallred.com) seems to show the blog I'm trying to host, but I exit and leave it alone for a while and it seems to start showing an index of files:

```
Index of /

HEAD
branches/
cgi-bin/
config
description
hooks/
info/
objects/
refs/
```

I'm not exactly sure where that directory is coming from or what's going on, despite hours of digging into the documentation.

EDIT: Here is the [url].conf file located in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name [url].com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }
}
```

There's nothing in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

Comment: You'll need to include your nginx configuration (sanitized) to be able to know what's up here.

Comment: @jdewald I added it to the edits. Is this the file you're talking about?

Comment: You're sure it's not GHOST doing it (or whatever is behind :2368). Also there could be a main nginx config that is setting a root path.

Comment: @jdewald I'm not sure at all :) Is there a way to find if there's another nginx config running? This is all new to me so hard to diagnose

Comment: You can check for something like /etc/nginx/nginx.conf or /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf. I would also try curling your local port 2368 and setting the appropriate Host header to determine what the application your are proxy_passing to is doing. There's nothing about the nginx config you're showing that would do a directory bit.

Comment: @jdewald interesting, thanks. It might be ghost going down periodically.